What value can the -qscale/ffmpeg parameter have?
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html
 -c:v libwebp -qscale:v

I use the libwebp codec, as I understand it. The image quality is relative to the codec that is used. But I can't find any documentation on libwebp.
What is the minimum and maximum value that the parameter can take -qscale?

When can I use -q:v?
The MPEG* encoders (mpeg4, mpeg2video, mpeg1video, mjpeg, libxvid, msmpeg4) can use -q:v / -qscale:v.
See How can I extract a good quality JPEG image from a video file with ffmpeg? for more info on this option.
Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64039472/16537476
